# How to execute two java files in two different daughters-directories from the mother directory

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a clean MVC code and to do that I tried to make a directory where the Model part is, a directory where the View part is etc..
So my tree is like this :

Project\

1. Model
2. View
3. Controller

in Project I have my Main.java, and I would like to do :
javac Main.java
then
java Main

But Main can't find the classes in Model and View.

I tried things I found while looking on google, but I can't find the answer, can you help me ?

Comment: Did you _import_ those classes?

Comment: I do now, i found the answer finally, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally !
Simply put :
package nameOfPackage;

on top of every class you want to be part of this package and then in the main just :

import nameOfPackage.*;